# Randomly listing entries in more then one section

Tags: templating

I have created 12 sponsorship ads for my website using a “sponsor” category.

On my home page I have four sponsorship sections, each holding three sponsorship ads.

How can I randomly distribute those 12 sponsorship ads among the four sponsorship areas with each homepage load?

Answer (score 1):

I would just [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) the randomized array of categories:

```
{% set ads = craft.categories({
    group: 'ads',
    order: 'RAND()'
}) %}

{% for ad in ads|slice(0, 2) %}
    {{ ad.externalUrl }}
{% endfor %}

{% for ad in ads|slice(2, 4) %}
    {{ ad.externalUrl }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, Carlos. Will try that right away.